# default image if file not exist mysql pdo

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to add a default image in a query, if the file does not exist.
I succeeded when the query doesn't have a while loop. But since i need to loop this values. i would like to add the default image to the query.

I wont get any errors, its just printing out some random info from my DB.

```
function fetch_tweets($uid){ 
    $uid = (int)$uid;
    $query = $this->link->query
         ("SELECT user.id, user.email, user.username,  tweets.message, tweets.date, 
          userdetails.profile_img, userdetails.firstname, userdetails.lastname, 
          following.id, following.user_id, following.follow_id
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN 
        following ON user.id = following.user_id 
    JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
    JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
    WHERE user.id='{$uid}'  
    OR 
            user.id IN (SELECT follow_id 
    FROM following 
    WHERE 
        following.user_id = '{$uid}' )  
    GROUP BY tweets.date ORDER BY tweets.date DESC "
    ); 

     $tweet = array();
     while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !==FALSE) { 
     $tweet[] = $row;
     $tweet['profile_img'] = (file_exists("img/{$uid}.jpg")) ?
     "img/{$uid}.jpg" :  "img/default.jpg" ;

}   
    return $tweet; 
}
```

Comment: PDO has nothing to do with files. it is a database driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the variable $tweet in the wrong way in your loop.

The following line will add a new element to the array $tweet:

```
$tweet[] = $row;
```

And the following line updates the element called "profile_img" in your $tweet array:

```
$tweet['profile_img'] = "...";
```

But I think, what you want is something like this:

```
while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) { 
    // Update the value for profile_img in the row
    $row['profile_img'] = file_exists("img/{$uid}.jpg") ? "img/{$uid}.jpg" :  "img/default.jpg" ;
    // Add the manipulated row to the $tweet-array
    $tweet[] = $row;
}
```

Please test using a debugger like xdebug (maybe a bit complicated to set up if you're not familiar with PHP) or just use var_dump();. You would've found that out pretty soon ...

Comment: Thank you, I tried the var_dump. but im quite new so sometimes I really don't know what to look after. this worked like a charm. Thank you mate.